# mac apache /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf vs /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-high-sierra

I'm trying to understand the difference between

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

on a Mac running High Sierra & PHP 7.1. Changes to both these files seemed to affect my localhost when I was getting up and running (apache stopped working when I upgraded to High Sierra). Perhaps I was: 1. accidentally modifying the wrong config at times, or 2. accidentally switching between apache installs?

`httpd -V` in the terminal shows `SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf"` and `phpinfo()` has `Loaded Configuration File: /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini` so I assume `/usr/local/*` is the correct (or just active?) configuration.  I touched these `/private/*` files during configuration but they no longer seem to be necessary:

```
/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
/private/etc/apache2/users/{username}.conf
/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
```

These seem to be the correct configs:

```
/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

What is the duplicate apache2 install in `/private/etc/apache2/*` for and can it safely be un-installed or removed?

Comment: It seems as if apache is using the /private/... path for some mirroring purposes. In my case i had only edited the  files nested in /etc/apache2/extra/  directory, after restarting the apache, those changes has been also applied in /private/ directory.  For that I would suggest not to delete those files.